# How can I call dictionary for entered key by user?

Tags: python-3.x, function, dictionary, monthcalendar

I want to call the given number for month. I want output to be like "Number of days in January is 30" if the user entered 1 etc.

```
 while True:
 month_dict = {
    "1": "January",
    "2": "February",
    "3": "March",
    "4": "April",
    "5": "May",
    "6": "June",
    "7": "July",
    "8": "August",
    "9": "September",
    "10": "October",
    "11": "November",
    "12": "December" 
    }

month = int(input("Enter the number of month:"))

def number_of_date(month):
    for value in month_dict.items():
        if month in [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12]:
            print("Number of days in", value, "is 31!!!")
        elif month in [4, 6, 9, 11]:
            print("Number of days in", value, "is 30!!!")
        elif month == 2:
            print("Number of days in", value, "is 28!!!")
        else:
            print("There is not a month like that.. Check your writing!")

number_of_date(month)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Just a little reordering and fixing up required. Groundwork was pretty solid.

```
month_dict = {
    1: "January", # removed "" around the numbers, because inputs are immediately converted to ints.
    2: "February",
    3: "March",
    4: "April",
    5: "May",
    6: "June",
    7: "July",
    8: "August",
    9: "September",
    10: "October",
    11: "November",
    12: "December" 
    }
    
def number_of_date(month): # removed for loop. You only need to print it once
    if month in [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12]:
        print("Number of days in", month_dict[month], "is 31!!!") # month_dict[month] returns the correct name.
    elif month in [4, 6, 9, 11]:
        print("Number of days in", month_dict[month], "is 30!!!")
    elif month == 2:
        print("Number of days in", month_dict[month], "is 28!!!")
    else:
        print("There is not a month like that.. Check your writing!")


while True: #while loop only around function call. No need to redefine functions every time
    month = int(input("Enter the number of month:"))
    number_of_date(month)  
#notice that your program will never end. Maybe loop only while month != -1. So -1 can be used to exit the program.
```

Comment: Spot on.  One enhancement will be to consider `leap` year...  ;-) Of course, that's not PO's req. yet.

Answer (score 1):

#### Declare the keys of `month_dict` as `int`

The main problem is that keys in `month_dict` are strings. If you change them to ints:

```
month_dict = {
    1: "January",
    2: "February",
    3: "March",
    4: "April",
    5: "May",
    6: "June",
    7: "July",
    8: "August",
    9: "September",
    10: "October",
    11: "November",
    12: "December" 
    }
```

You can then simply use `month_dict[month]`to obtain the name of the month associated with it's number.

#### Drop the `for` loop

Losing the `for` inside the function will make it print a single final result.

#### Remove the declaration of `month_dict` and `number_of_date(month)` out of the `while`

Finally, also consider doing this to avoid declaring the same values over and over.

Here's the full code:

```py
month_dict = {
    1: "January",
    2: "February",
    3: "March",
    4: "April",
    5: "May",
    6: "June",
    7: "July",
    8: "August",
    9: "September",
    10: "October",
    11: "November",
    12: "December" 
    }



def number_of_date(month):
    if month in [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12]:
        print("Number of days in", month_dict[month], "is 31!!!")
    elif month in [4, 6, 9, 11]:
        print("Number of days in", month_dict[month], "is 30!!!")
    elif month == 2:
        print("Number of days in", month_dict[month], "is 28!!!")
    else:
        print("There is not a month like that.. Check your writing!")

while True:
    month = int(input("Enter the number of month:"))
    number_of_date(month)
```

I think that's it!
If you want to check for leap years next see [this tutorial](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/leap-year).